# Как сделать проверку ссылки youtube на существование видео?

Tags: youtube

Подскажите кто знает.
Как сделать проверку ссылки youtube на существование видео?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Достаньте из url ID видео и сделайте запрос к API

https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/**0OSNouPNAm1**?v=2

Если видео не существует в ответ придет

```
<errors xmlns='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005'><error><domain>GData</domain><code>ResourceNotFoundException</code><internalReason>Video not found</internalReason></error></errors>
```

Еще можно сделать обращение к превью видео с его ID

http://img.youtube.com/vi/0OSNouPNAm1/1.jpg

Если видео не существует, ответ будет с кодом 404

Comment: Приведите пример пожалуйста, если не сложно, а то у меня что-то не получается

Comment: https://gist.github.com/LinnTroll/9692758

Answer (score 0):

Ну, как вариант, парсить страницу или смотреть номер ответа от сервера.

Comment: я тоже первым делом хотел предложить хедер смотреть, но ютуб всегда возвращает 200